# SERVER 500 error in my django app through heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-views, heroku-postgres, server-error

Showing SERVER ERROR 500 when my django app is deployed through heroku and when i try to enter details through post method into postgresql database:

```py
def register(request):
    if (request.method=="GET"):
        return render(request,'register.html',{'curl':curl,'output':''})
    else:   
        name=request.POST.get('name')
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        address=request.POST.get('address')
        mobile=request.POST.get('mobile')
        city=request.POST.get('city')
        gender=request.POST.get('gender')
        dt=time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))    
        query="insert into(name,email,password,address,mobile,city,gender,role,status,dt) register values('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','user',0,'%s')" %(name,email,password,address,mobile,city,gender,dt)
        models.cursor.execute(query)
        models.db.commit()
        import smtplib 
        from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
        from email.mime.text import MIMEText
        me = "hellomatcraft@gmail.com"
        you = email
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = "Verification Mail MatCraft"
        msg['From'] = me
        msg['To'] = you
        html = """<html>
                    <head></head>
                        <body>
                            <h1>Welcome to MatCraft</h1>
                            <p>You have successfully registered , please click on the link below to verify your account</p>
                            <h2>Username : """+email+"""</h2>
                            <h2>Password : """+str(password)+"""</h2>
                            <br>
                            <a href='https://matcraft.herokuapp.com/verify?vemail="""+email+"""' >Click here to verify account</a>      
                        </body>
                    </html>
                """
        s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
        s.starttls() 
        #login() 
    
        part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    
        msg.attach(part2)
    
        s.sendmail(me,you, str(msg)) 
        s.quit() 
        print("mail send successfully....")
                
        return render(request,'register.html',{'curl':curl,'output':'Verification Mail Successfully Send....'})'
```

This is the error:

> 2020-08-24T10:44:19.917608+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/register/" host=matcraft.herokuapp.com request_id=9255fbcd-a4dd-4be2-a059-5473259002ca fwd="157.34.125.241" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=58ms status=500 bytes=473 protocol=https

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide more context to your question - what kind of application this is, what exactly are you trying to achieve. This will make it easier for someone to help you.

Comment: it's a register function in views.py where we are getting details from the user using post method and then inserting it into our postgresql database and sending a verfication mail to the user who entered their email id

Comment: You're going to have to add some logging output to your function.